# ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function when using two joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following PostgreSQL:

```
select
    A.*,
    B.child,
    REGEXP_MATCHES(A.b_number, '([^.]*--[0-9]*).*') as number,
    sum(cast(A.amount AS decimal)) as sum_amount,
    count(A.amount) as cnt_amount
into result
from B
join A on B.name = A.name and B.parent = A.id
join C on A.name = C.name and B.child = C.id
group by A.name, A.unit, number;

select * from result;
```

But I get the following error:

> SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "A.index" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

What is the reason for this?

I tried adding **A.index** to the GROUP BY clause but it only kept asking for different columns. I also tried creating a subquery but failed because I have two joins and I'm trying to create a new table **result**.

Comment: Your `SELECT` clause says you want all columns from `A` but your `GROUP BY` clause only includes `name` and `unit`. So for any other column in `A`, when you're grouping there may be *multiple* rows with *multiple* values in those other columns. How is the system meant to know *which* value to select in each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version with the `GROUP BY` problem corrected:

```sql
SELECT
    A.name,
    A.unit,
    B.child,
    REGEXP_MATCHES(A.b_number, '([^.]*--[0-9]*).*') AS number,
    SUM(CAST(A.amount AS decimal)) AS sum_amount,
    COUNT(A.amount) AS cnt_amount
INTO result
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON B.name = A.name AND B.parent = A.id
INNER JOIN C ON A.name = C.name AND B.child = C.id
GROUP BY
    A.name,
    A.unit,
    B.child,
    number;
```

Note that every column/alias which appears in the `SELECT` clause also appears in `GROUP BY`.  Exceptions to this are columns which appear inside aggregate functions.  In that case, it is OK for them to not appear in `GROUP BY`.